# Alternative "null" value

Tags: c, memory-management, null

It seems common to have the tail pointer at the end of a linked list be null (0).

What if I want to have two possible different "tails"?

My use case is a big integer representation that supports two's complement: I want to have a tail corresponding to "the rest of this number is zeros" and "the rest of this number is ones", where I can tell them apart just by performing a pointer equality.

It seems like this should be common enough to have standard practice, but it's hard to think of exactly what to search for. It seems somewhat arbitrary that we only get one "forbidden" pointer value (that will give a useful-ish error when accidentally dereferenced).

Options seem to include:

- Use some arbitrary second value (like 1, or 0xdeadbeef). This seems evil. For one thing, I guess it needs to be aligned? Also, I will have obscure bugs if malloc happens to allocate a real linked list cell at the same address. Is there some region of memory malloc is guaranteed not to use?
- Call malloc with a dummy non-zero size. This seems more sensible, but ideally I would have the pointer value be const, rather than requiring initialisation.
- Take the address of something arbitrary, like a function defined in the file. This seems very evil, but does seem to lack any practical disadvantages (assuming it would work).

Comment: If you want "two tails" then that sounds more like a *tree* rather than a list.

Comment: If you can spare one more byte, maybe just add a flag field to the node that tells you, for a terminal node, whether the rest would be zeroes or ones.

Comment: On all real systems you will actually be writing programs on, (void*)1 is also an invalid pointer, and (void*)-1, and plenty of other small and big numbers. But this behaviour is platform-specific.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude It’s one of two possible values, not two simultaneous values.

Comment: Also notice that `malloc` allocates aligned memory, which means (on all platforms you will ever use) the lowest few bits of a malloced memory address are always 0.

Comment: Why not allocate and use an *actual* object to represent these tails? Using a fake `NULL` doesn’t seem fitting for your use-case. (Or, as mentioned, just set a (bit) flag.)

Comment: If you really need to do it in the pointer, the last alternative seems best. But rather than pointing to something arbitrary, declare a special global variable and point to that.

Comment: If I were going to use a linked list to represent a big integer, the head would be the ones place and the tail would be the most significant digit, because all calculations are performed from the right. That'd make the point how to store multiple leading zeros moot.

Comment: @Barmar That seems like a great idea, thank you!

Comment: If it's like @KonradRudolph says, then a special sentinel node might be used instead as suggested by others.

Comment: One last consideration: using a linked list to represent arbitrary precision numbers is virtually guaranteed to be a bad idea. Why are you not using an array/vector? Linked lists are a terribly inefficient data type on modern computer architectures for almost all use-cases.

Comment: @MOehm Indeed, it goes from lsb to msb. But I want to distinguish between a positive number (leading zeroes) and a negative number in two's complement (leading ones).

Comment: But in that case, you can calculate the count of the last number from the overall number of digits. It seems that your linked list elements are binary digits. In that case, you may not need a special null value: Use the convention that the digit of the tail node repeats: If `n->next == NULL`, then the number is positive if `n->bit == 0` and negative otherwise.

Comment: @MOehm that's what the asker is doing. How would you store a negative number in two's complement? An infinite number of 1s?

Comment: Using a function address is not a good idea because there are CPU architectures where the size of a function pointer is not equal the size of a data pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given some `ListItem` type and a desired to have a `ListItem *` value that serves as a [sentinel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentinel_value) (also see [sentinel node](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentinel_node)), we can simply define a `ListItem` object to serve that purpose:

```
ListItem SentinelObject;
ListItem * const SentinelValue = &SentinelObject;
```

This could also be made `static` if they will be used only in one translation unit.

The named object could be eliminated by using a compound literal:

```
ListItem * const SentinelValue = & (ListItem) {0};
```

(The initializer may need adjustment if `0` is not a suitable initailizer for the first member of `ListItem`.)

Alternately, wasting space could be avoided by overlapping the unused `ListItem` object with some other object:

```
union { SomeUsefulType SomeUsefulThing; ListItem SentinelObject; } MyUnion;
ListItem * const SentinelValue = &MyUnion.SentinelObject;
```

While this gives `SomeUsefulThing` and `SentinelObject` the same address, that is unlikely to be a problem given they have different types.